# Can you use macOS "log stream" or "log show" to get messages from connected iOS devices?

Tags: ios, logging, macos-sierra

With the introduction of "Unified Logging" in macOS 10.12 Sierra, one can use the `log` command to view system log messages in a terminal. For example

```
sudo log stream
```

or

```
sudo log stream --process `pgrep -f /usr/local/bin/myprogram` --info --debug
```

or

```
log show --predicate 'process == "myprogram"' --last 1h --info --debug
```

Using the new "unified" Console.app, one can view system messages and can also view messages from connected iOS devices.

Is there any way to use the `log` command or any other command-line interface to view iOS device messages in Terminal, or to send them to a file?  Or is Console.app the only way?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: It's old and I haven't tried it, but you should take a look on this project, perhaps it will do the trick:
https://github.com/benvium/libimobiledevice-macosx

Also, please note it's not part of the unified logger, it's just another tool to grep using terminal instead of console

Comment: @Jan does my answer help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `log collect —device`

`log collect --device` lets you retrieve log archives that can be passed into `log show --archive system_logs.logarchive` with all the options you're familiar with.

Use `log collect --device` to automatically guess the device you're referring to.
`log collect device-name="Maxs iPhone"` or `log collect device-udid=abcdefg` to collect from a particular device.

`log collect --output /your/path` will save it to your specified file name or directory.  If `--output` is not given, your output will be in the current directory as `system_logs.logarchive`.

Note: I occasionally get errors about `log: failed to create archive: Device not configured (6)` or `log: failed to create archive: Connection reset by peer (54)` but if I just rerun the command it'll sometimes work ‍♀️

Comment: This means there really is no option to stream from a device? Crazy .. So we need to use Console.app :/

Comment: "--device" option seems only been introduced with mac os 10.15, previously collecting logs from a device was not available?

Comment: I get "log: failed to create archive: Device not configured (6)" every time. I don't see a fix anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have it set as a development device?  Connect the device via Lightning to your Mac, open Xcode and go to "Devices and Simulators", and try adding your iOS device

Comment: For "failed to create archive" I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766647/3221771

Answer (score 2):

You can, using third-party OSS tools.

https://libimobiledevice.org

These are available using homebrew. `brew install libimobiledevice`

You can discover available devices (UDIDs) by running `idevice_id`. Then start streaming logs by running `idevicesyslog -n -u <udid>`