# How to collect logs from iPhone correctly and how to resolve this error: failed to create archive?

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, terminal

As discussed in WWDC video [Explore Logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/), one can use the ***log collect*** command to collect device logs from a connected iOS device.

The command looks like this.

```
sudo log collect --device-name "Someone's iPhone" --start "2022-01-19"
```

However, I have encountered the following error while running this command

> log: failed to create archive: Device not configured (6)

Any hints to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when the Mac could not connect to the iPhone by WLAN. When I connected it by cable, the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the device name does not include apostrophe. So you have to go to Settings -> General -> About -> Name (of your iOS device).
Tap on the name to change name of your device and make sure there is no apostrophe.

So the following command will produce error

```
sudo log collect --device-name "Bob's iPhone" --start "2022-01-19"
```

If Bob changed his device name to 'Bobs iPhone' (as discussed above) and wrote in terminal

```
sudo log collect --device-name "Bobs iPhone" --start "2022-01-19"
```

It should work